# Do hashes repeat themselves?

Tags: hash

I am not sure how hashing works exactly, all I know it is impossible to reverse it.
All hash types have X amount of characters in them while the phrases and made up words can have an infinite quantity hence infinitely more times than the character counts in a hash.
So do hashes repeat themselves?

Comment: lookup the term: "collision"

Comment: Btw, the preimage is not always infinitely large, see the `max message size column` in the [wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Comparison_of_SHA_functions).

Comment: @user10008 So for most hash methods it would be 67108863, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible because of the limited length, but it has a very little chance.
Read a bit about hash collision, for example: http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/

Answer (score 1):

The thing that you are asking about is called hash collision.

To make it extremely simple let's say your hash has 1 byte (=8 bits). This means that you can assign a distinct hash to at most 2^8 messages. If you had 2^8 + 1 (257) messages you would definitely experience a collision.

Now let's fast forward to todays situation. MD5 for example has 128 bits. This means it can encode 2^128 (3.4028237e+38) messages at most. So if you have a good algorithm (this is very important) your collision rate will be negligible and you will be able to assign a distinct hash to almost every of 2^128 distinct messages.

Comment: MD5 isn't really a good example of a hash collision free algo